# Reading just 1 column from a file using NumPy's loadtxt() function

Tags: numpy

I want to read in data from multiple files that I want to use for plotting (matplotlib).

I found a function `loadtxt()` that I could use for this purpose. However, I only want to read in one column from each file.

How would I do this?
The following command works for me if I read in at least 2 columns, for example:

```
numpy.loadtxt('myfile.dat', usecols=(2,3))
```

But

```
numpy.loadtxt('myfile.dat', usecols=(3))
```

would throw an error.

Comment: For more advanced text loading (e.g., handling of missing values) you can also use NumPy's [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need a comma after the 3 in order to tell Python that `(3,)` is a tuple. Python interprets `(3)` to be the same value as the int `3`, and `loadtxt` wants a sequence-type argument for `usecols`.

```
numpy.loadtxt('myfile.dat', usecols=(3,))
```

Comment: Ahh, didn't think of that. It's the first time I was using NumPy, thanks!

Comment: Or `usecols=[3]` if you don't want to use the comma.